# Parent not passing value to child

Tags: angular

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.
In my parent component.html for attribute title I assigned string 'popup1':

```
                <dropmenu [title]='popup1' [items]="getContextMenuItems(node)" (onSelect)="onClick($event)" 
             [dropdownStyles]="{'left': 'calc(100% - 120px)'}" docRowId="{{node.id}}" [addTabIndex]="node.active" >
```

In the dropmenu child component:

```
                template: `
                <div #dropmenu class="dropmenu" style="height:16px" (contextmenu)="rightClick($event)" focusout-close (onFocusout)="closeOptions()" id="dropmenu_{{docRowId}}" title="{{title}}">
                  <div class="item-area">Albert11
                </div>
                </div>


                export class DropMenuComponent {
              @Input('items') items: any[] = [];
              @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
              @Input() dropdownStyles: any = {};
              @Input('docRowId') docRowId: string;
              @ViewChild('dropmenu') dropmenu: ElementRef;
              @Input('addTabIndex') addTabIndex:boolean = false;
               
              @Input('title') title: string;
```

But I don't see the value of title being pass from parent to child component in the element.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What is `popup1`? Is that a variable or did you want to pass `popup1` as the string value itself?. If latter, then try title without the property binding.

using [title] looks at a value of the variable called `popup1`. In your case since you just want to pass the string `popup1`, use `title='popup1'` instead of `[title]='popup1'` without the square brackets.

```
  <dropmenu title='popup1' [items]="getContextMenuItems(node)" (onSelect)="onClick($event)" 
             [dropdownStyles]="{'left': 'calc(100% - 120px)'}" docRowId="{{node.id}}" [addTabIndex]="node.active" >
```

Comment: "popup1" is supposed to be a string.

Comment: Sorry can you please tell me how to try title without the property binding means?

Comment: Use `title='popup1'` instead of `[title]='popup1'`

Comment: Thank you so much Preetha Pinto. It works. I thought for a parent component to pass value to child component you need [title]='popup1' why does it work with title='popup1'. From angular url: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction it says to use [title] for parent component to child component.

Comment: updated the answer to add explanation. See if it helps.